# Trying to use pipenv on fresh ubuntu install, does not allow me to use python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to figure out how to properly use pipenv. I have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS install.

I installed pipenv

```
$sudo apt install pipenv
```

And it seems I can successfully create a virtual environment by running

```
$ pipenv --python 3.8
```

However, I tried to create an environment for python 3.10 and at first it failed because it could not find python 3.10 on my system.

> Python 3.10 was not found on your system... You can specify specific
> versions of Python with: $ pipenv --python path/to/python

So I installed 3.10 like this:

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$sudo apt install python3.10
$which python3.10
$/usr/bin/python3.10
```

I should now have python 3.10 on my system, I now try

```
$pipenv --python /usr/bin/python3.10
```

And now I get all this:

> Creating a virtualenv for this project…

> Using /usr/bin/python3.10 (3.10.2) to create virtualenv…

> ⠋RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.10 with code 1 err: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py:16: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives\n  from distutils.command.install import SCHEME_KEYS\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 16, in \n    from distutils.command.install import SCHEME_KEYS\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.command'\n'
> Error while trying to remove the /home/balmes/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-p0eTKeXl env:
> No such file or directory

> Virtualenv location:

> Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.8, but you are using None (/bin/python).
> $ pipenv check will surely fail.

Can somebody please explain what's going on? Thanks!!!

Comment: Install distutils? `sudo apt install python3.10-distutils`

Comment: That seems to have helped! The virtualenv is getting created

Creating a virtualenv for this project...

Using /usr/bin/python3.10 (3.10.2) to create virtualenv...
created virtual environment CPython3.10.2.final.0-64 in 122ms
creator CPython3Posix(dest =...
seeder FromAppData(download=....

Virutalenv location: /home/balmes/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-p0eTKeXL

Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.8, but you are using 3.10.2 (/home/balmes/.local/share/v/t/bin/python).
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.

Comment: If I run $pipenv check I get the following:

Comment: Specifier python_version does not match 3.8 (3.1). Failed!

Comment: I can get into the pipenv shell but if I try to install anything else (pandas, django, scipy) I get a bunch of errors and the same warning about my Pipfile requires python_version 3.8 but I am using 3.10.2

Comment: Try removing the venv and recreating it? `pipenv --rm`

Comment: I went into the Pipfile that was created. For some reason it says
[requires]
python_version = "3.8"

Comment: Maybe left over from a previous venv? Glad you got it sorted

Comment: It still gave me errors when I manually edited the Pipfile. However removing it and recreating it seems to have solved things. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I still get an error when I run $pipenv check:


Checking PEP 508 requirements…
Specifier python_version does not match 3.10 (3.1).
Failed!

Comment: But everything else works! I can add pandas and django